# C++ - "Unspecialised class template" error with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr

I have a class Room and it holds a vector of shared_ptrs to Option objects like so:

```
private:
vector<shared_ptr<Option> > options;
```

But for some reason when I build, I get the following errors:

- 'shared_ptr' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter '_Ty', expected a real type
- 'std::tr1::shared_ptr' : use of class template requires template argument list

Strangely, I also have a vector of shared_ptrs, exact same syntax but there's no problem with that one.

There's also a bunch of places that bring up the error "'Option': undeclared identifier", which brings me to think it might be a problem with the Option class, but it seems to be fine. Here's the code for Option:

Option.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Room.h"
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Option
{
protected:
    int id;
    char* text;

public:
    Option(void);
    Option(int, char*);
    virtual ~Option(void);
    char* getText();
    int getID();
};
```

Option.cpp:

```
#include "Option.h"
#include "Room.h"
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

Option::Option(void)
{
}

Option::Option(int newID, char* newText){
    id = newID;
    text = newText;
}

Option::~Option(void)
{
}

char* Option::getText(){
    return text;
}

int Option::getID(){
    return id;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<Option> > options; ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bit of conjecture in this answer since you haven't posted the code for the `Room` class. I'm assuming this code

```
private:
vector<shared_ptr<Option> > options;
```

is in *Room.h*. Your *Option.h* file includes *Room.h*, hence the `Room` class gets declared before the `Option` class. So `Option` is an incomplete type when the `Room` class' destructor is compiled and the `shared_ptr` implementation tries to delete the `Option` object.

From the code above, I don't see why *Option.h* needs to include *Room.h*, in fact, it should be the other way around. If it does indeed need to include the file, you should be able to work around the problem by explicitly declaring `Room::~Room()` out-of-line in *Room.cpp*.

**EDIT:**
Turns out `~shared_ptr<T>` [does not require T to be a complete type](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/incomplete.html). However, `shared_ptr<T>( T* )` and `shared_ptr<T>::reset( T* )` do, and the problem may be because some operation on the `vector` is invoking a call to one of these (more likely the former).

Comment: oOoh I see,that makes sense. I do need ro reference room in option because I have "virtual shared_ptr<Room> getRoom();" too, which is overridden in a subclass RoomOption. I have declared the Room destructor which apparently hasn't fixed it...

Comment: I figured out a way of referencing the Room in Option by using an int ID instead of an actual reference to a Room. I'd still like to know why the destructor isn't working the way you suggested though, if you have any insight.

Comment: @JeanFinley I was mistaken in claiming that `spared_ptr` destructor requires `T` to be a complete type, [it doesn't](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/incomplete.html). However, as shown in that link, `shared_ptr<T>( T* )` and `shared_ptr<T>::reset( T* )` both require `T` to be a complete type. So try commenting code from the member functions of `Room` that may invoke a call to either. Remember that since you have a `vector` any operation that mutates the `vector` could be the culprit too.

Comment: @JeanFinley Also, *Option.h* does not need to include *Room.h* just because the `virtual shared_ptr<Room> getRoom();` member function has been declared in, simply forward declare the `Room` class as `class Room;` instead of including the header. *Option.cpp* will probably need to include *Room.h*, but that's OK since by removing it from the header you've gotten rid of the circular dependency.

Comment: I commented out everything in Room to do with Option (apart from the vector itself) and it still isn't working. I'll put up the code for Room now

Comment: Forward declaration (which I just learned about when you mentioned it) worked. I owe you ten million cookies. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
vector<shared_ptr<Option >>
```

You *almost* did that right :)

```
vector<shared_ptr<Option> >
```

It's the two `>` characters that, when touching, cause the strange errors you see.  It is being interpreted as the `>>` operator.

BTW, thank you for posting your code *exactly as it is* rather than typing it back in and possibly hiding the mistake.

Comment: Doh! Thanks. Fixed it but I'm still having the same problem. Strangely, I also have a vector of shared_ptrs to Item objects (same syntax but with Item instead of Object) and that one works fine... Also, thank you for being so nice ^_^